# React.js - incrementing state object value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a state 'users' which contain the list of users. I would like to increment a user value "count" on click, initial "count" value is 1. The behaviour is supposed to be: You have a list of users, after clicking a particular user you get redirected to /userdetail/:user_twitter_name where you can click the Vote for user button which will increment the user.count value += 1, in the first run from 1 to 2.

```js
  /* actions/counter.js */

    export function userVoted(user) {
      return {
        type: 'USER_VOTED',
        payload: user.count
      };
    }

      
    /* reducers/reducer_user_vote.js */
      
    export default function(state = null, action) {
      switch(action.type) {
      case 'USER_VOTED':
          return (action.payload + 1);
      }
      return state;
    }


    /* reducers/index.js */
      
    import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
    import UserReducer from './reducer_user';
    import ActiveUser from './reducer_active_user';
    import userVoted from './reducer_user_vote';

    const rootReducer = combineReducers({
      users: UserReducer,
      activeUser: ActiveUser,
      userVoted: userVoted
    });


    /* reducers/reducer_user.js */

    export default function () {
      return [
        {username: 'John Doe', email: 'john@doe.com', twitter: 'johndoe1', count: 1},
        {username: 'Paul Smith', email: 'smith.paul@csswizardry.com', twitter: 'csswizardry', count: 1},
        {username: 'Petra Tweets', email: 'petra@tweets.me.com', twitter: 'petra', count: 1},
        {username: 'Mark Chills', email: 'chillmark@company.com', twitter: 'chillymark12', count: 1},
        {username: 'John McIntyre', email: 'comic@mcintyre.com', twitter: 'jokesforfun', count: 1},
      ];
    }
        

    export default rootReducer;


    /* components/seconddetail.js */


    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { Router, Link } from 'react-router';
    import { userVoted } from '../actions/counter';
    import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';



    class SecondDetail extends Component {


      render() {

        if (!this.props.params.twitter) {
          return <div>Select a user to view details.</div>;
        }

        // Filtered User that matches the URL param
        const filteredUser = this.props.users.filter((user) => {
          if (user.twitter == this.props.params.twitter) {
            return user;
          }
        });

        const resultUser = filteredUser[0];

        return (
          <div className="detail">
            <h2 className="text-center">Details:</h2>
            <br />
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-3 text-center">
                <i className="fa fa-user fa-4x"></i>
                <br/>
                {resultUser.username}
              </div>
              <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-3 text-center">
                <i className="fa fa-envelope-o fa-4x"></i>
                <br/>
                {resultUser.email}
              </div>
              <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-3 text-center">
                <i className="fa fa-twitter fa-4x"></i>
                <br/>
                {resultUser.twitter}
              </div>
              <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-3 text-center">
                <i className="fa fa-star fa-4x"></i>
                <br/>
                {resultUser.count}
              </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-xs-12 text-center">
                  <div className="btn btn-success" onClick={() => this.props.userVoted(resultUser)}>Vote for user</div>
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <Link to={'/'} className="btn btn-primary">Home</Link>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
      return {
        users: state.users
      };
    }

    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
      return bindActionCreators({ userVoted }, dispatch);
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SecondDetail);

    /* index.js */

    
    import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

import App from './components/app';
import DetailComponent from './components/detailcomponent';
import SecondDetail from './components/seconddetail';
import reducers from './reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware()(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App} />
        <Route path="/detail" component={DetailComponent} />
        <Route path="/userdetail/:twitter" component={SecondDetail} />
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

However, on item click the function gets called (I can see values in the console when I console.log() inside the function) but the value for the particular user is not increased. Could you advise? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I can't see all of the code but it looks like your state shape is:

```
{
  users: UserReducer,
  activeUser: ActiveUser,
  userVoted: userVoted
}
```

In your *render* function you are rendering the count as *resultUser.count* but I can't see this being updated in any reducer. (I can just see the user voted reducer updating the *userVoted* part of the state (an integer?)). If *userVoted* is an integer how do you know to which user it applies?

So, you may have to amend your *mapStateToProps* so that you can update the count for each user, or actualy amend your state shape.

**Edit**

Further to comments below; if you want to update the user count directly in the userReducer you can use the logic below (it will need putting into the reducer's switch statement for the 'USER_VOTED' action), the code below is just to show how to amend the array of users:

```
var state = [
        {username: 'John Doe', email: 'john@doe.com', twitter: 'johndoe1', count: 1},
        {username: 'Paul Smith', email: 'smith.paul@csswizardry.com', twitter: 'csswizardry', count: 1},
        {username: 'Petra Tweets', email: 'petra@tweets.me.com', twitter: 'petra', count: 1},
        {username: 'Mark Chills', email: 'chillmark@company.com', twitter: 'chillymark12', count: 1},
        {username: 'John McIntyre', email: 'comic@mcintyre.com', twitter: 'jokesforfun', count: 1},
      ];


var action = {
    type:  'USER_VOTED',
    user:  {username: 'Mark Chills', email: 'chillmark@company.com', twitter: 'chillymark12', count: 1}
};

var newState = state.map(u => {
  return action.user.username === u.username ? Object.assign({}, u, { count: u.count + 1} ) : u;
});



console.log(newState);
```

NB I've had to match in *username*, meaning this would have to be unique, an *id* would be better.

Comment: The problem is I need to find a way to increment the count value for each user individually. I can't store the count value in userVoted as each user will have a different count value. resultUser is only the user from the users array which fits the filter for the current user by the URL parameter

Comment: I agree, that's what I was trying to say. So, you could amend the reducer so that it incremented the appropriate user (obviously the action payload would have to define which user), or amend userVoted so that it was an array of objects containing user id and count.

Comment: How can I make the reducer to increment the appropriate user's count value? That's what I was trying to achieve but with no success. Thanks

Comment: If you are going to update the user itself I guess it will be a case in your user reducer (which I can't see). This will have to clone the user (no mutation in redux!) and increment its count and then return the array of users again avoiding mutation either by mapping over the array of users or using the spread operator and slice.

Comment: My user reducers is located in reducers/reducer_user.js , you can see it in the code above, it just returns a static array for now.

Comment: Ah right, so that will have to have a switch case for 'USER_VOTED' and update the appropriate user (map might be the best approach - it will return a new array of users).

Comment: I've updated my original answer with an example to point you in the right direction.